# Reactjs - append Object to a Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to add a object to a sub objecto but I got some errors, some could help me? this is my code, thanks:
Obs:I've used 'push' and got the error msg: push is not defined.

```
if(this.state.upd != '' && this.state.image1 == ''){
  cadastro.imagens.push({1:this.state.img[1]?this.state.img[1]:""});
}else {
   cadastro.imagens.push({1:this.state.image1});
}
```

And if I use like that it subscribe the others

```
if(this.state.upd != '' && this.state.image2 == ''){
  cadastro.imagens = {2:this.state.img[2]?this.state.img[2]:""};
}else {
   cadastro.imagens = {2:this.state.image2};
}
```

Comment: Please share with us your whole state and `cadastro` data. Also, if you explain a little bit more about what are you trying to do here, it will be better.

Comment: let cadastro = { imagens:{0:'', 1:'',2:'',3:'', },lat:''} Cadastro is something like this

Comment: The code is too big to put here, but basic what Im trying to do is, if user already has a image and don't choose other, I gonna take the old image uploaded else I get the new image and set the new object

Comment: I'm asking for the details because I don't know where the `cadastro` is? If it is in the state then assigning some properties means you are mutating the state and you shouldn't do that. Other than that manipulating objects is not so hard.

Answer (score 2):

```
let cadastro = { imagens:{0:'', 1:'',2:'',3:'', },lat:''}
```

From this we can see that type of imagens in object and object do not have .push() method
But to achieve the result you want you can

```
cadastro.imagens[1] = this.state.img[1]?this.state.img[1]:"";
```

So your code will look like

```
if(this.state.upd != '' && this.state.image1 == ''){
  cadastro.imagens[1] = this.state.img[1]?this.state.img[1]:""
}else {
   cadastro.imagens[1] = this.state.image1
}
```

Comment: @JaderCosta glad to hear that. If this ans helped you then you can also accept this ans :-)

Answer (score 0):

Push only works on an array but not on object. You can override object key value using **.** notation too followed by key name. Something like below

```
const cadastro = { imagens:{0:'', 1:'',2:'',3:'', },lat:''};

//ovverride key value using .notation
cadastro.imagens.1 = this.state.img[1]?this.state.img[1]:"";


if(this.state.upd != '' && this.state.image1 == ''){
  cadastro.imagens.1 = this.state.img[1]?this.state.img[1]:"";
}else {
   cadastro.imagens.1 = this.state.image1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I don't have much background on what data structure are you using. But, I am assuming that you are creating an object `imagens` which is supposed to hold an array of images which the user has uploaded. (In this case, I assume a user uploads two images)

Here's a suggestion, because I feel the way you are assigning it looks bad on the programming bit of things.

You can type cast your object to an array like -

```
cadastro.imagens = []
```

and then you can push your values in it like -

```
cadastro.imagens.push(this.state.img[1]?this.state.img[1]:"");
```

if you are not creating this object, and its already present, you can do - (which again I don't feel good about but anyway)

```
cadastro.imagens[1] = this.state.img[1]?this.state.img[1]:"";
```